# How to loop through json array of objects in angular to extract all objects?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, loops, object

I'm struggling to display specific objects from an array of objects in a table. I want to display, in two separate columns, values of "treshold" and "pointsToAdd". Currently, all I am extracting is displayed in one column (instead of two) as:
[Object object], [Object object], [Object object], [Object object]

I'm a beginner and cannot figure a most suitable way to do that with typescript.

=======================================================
JSON Code:

```
[{
    "treshold": [
        { "treshold": 35, "pointsToAdd": 10 },
        { "treshold": 50, "pointsToAdd": 20 },
        { "treshold": 75, "pointsToAdd": 30 },
        { "treshold": 100, "pointsToAdd": 40 }],
    "_id": "5d6f3acd4d94a08064f4bd11",
    "is_active": true,
    "date": "20190904"
}]
```

======================================
My component.ts code:

```
export class TresholdComponent implements OnInit {

  posts: any=[];
  treshold: string;
  pointsToAdd: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('http://urladdress').subscribe(posts =>{
      this.posts = posts;})
  }
}
```

=======================================
My component.html code:

```
<table class="table table-borderless user-table">
    <thead class="thead-border">
      <tr>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center table-checkbox">
          <mat-checkbox class=""></mat-checkbox>
        </div>
          <td scope="col">Treshold</td>
          <td scope="col">Points to add</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let post of posts">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center table-checkbox">
          <mat-checkbox></mat-checkbox>
        </div>
          <td>{{post.treshold}}</td>
          <td>{{post.pointsToAdd}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: it looks like you are iterating through the 1st array and treshold and pointsToAdd are in the inner array (of treshold)

Comment: DIV inside table and out of TDs looks like an error (probably invalid HTML) and what if you set that array in init ? this.posts = posts.treshold

Comment: @BillCheng that is the issue from what I figured out. How do I iterate through the inner arrays of that array?

TOM: I didn't copy the enclosing </div> and removed the original html to post here. using "this.posts = posts.treshold" results in not displaying anything at all

Comment: to get it working, you may try `this.posts = posts[0].treshold` but there is a problem... you will need to make sure posts is an array and has a length of at least 1. And what if there are more than 1 element in the posts array? do you have to render them as well?

Comment: Sorry did not noticed or you can fake it in case for example by (length < 1 would be false for undefined @Object)  if(!this.posts || !this.posts.length > 0) this.posts = [ { "treshold": "", "pointsToAdd": "" }];